# Execute fontforge in php

Tags: python, execute

I wrote a script using Fontforge to Edit and generate fonts
it works fine when i call this script through the terminal 
but i need to call this script using php  command line 
and it's not working

the regular terminal command is

```
Fontforge script.py args.json
```

this command line is not working with php 
as usual, php works with commands starts with

```
exec("Python")
```

or

```
exec("java")
```

but my command start with `fontforge script.py`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)

Comment: it doesn't work for me fontforge is not working from php command line

Comment: Define "is not working". Your code is using a different command line than the one used in terminal.